# htaccess redirecting a slash to get parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have set up redirecting like this:

```
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]*)$ /file.php?name=$1 [L]
```

which basically does this:

```
example.com/file/somefilename.png --> example.com/file.php?name=somefilename.png
```

It redirects fine but when I try doing file.php it seemingly doesn't care about what is after the slash.

I did try some ways to get it to work with file.php, but just couldn't get it to work.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean you try to get it to work with file.php? Is that the file you are trying to rewrite to? How are you trying use  file.php and what is your expected outcome?

Comment: Basically I want both of these: example.com/file/somefilename.png and example.com/file.php/somefilename.png to redirect over to: example.com/file.php?name=somefilename.png but with that redirect rule the second of the ones I want to be redirected (One with file.php) doesn't get redirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure multiviews is turned off by adding:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Multiviews is part of mod_negotiation which tries to "guess" what files you're requesting by partial matches. So when it sees `/file/`, it thinks you mean `/file.php/`, which causes the rewrite rule to get bypassed.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't help, I think in this case the problem is that the current rewrite rule is not even looking for file.php, all it cares about is just file

Comment: @Newjorciks why would it look for `file.php`? Your regex clearly says `/file/`.

Comment: Yeah, but that is the thing I need, I need it to work on file.php/ as well as file/, I did seem to get that to work, but it was "buggy" sometimes did work, sometimes didn't and going to it through sub-domain (Which leads to file.php and has redirecting allowed) just threw an internal server error.

Comment: Then change the rule to: `RewriteRule ^file(?:\.php|)/([^/]*)$ /file.php?name=$1 [L]`

Comment: Alright, thanks, that did work, now I just need to figure out why it throws Internal Server Error 500 if I go to file.php through subdomain that sends me to it :D